# Create data table in geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-9.3, vb.net

Using vb.net, my custom tool needs to create a data table in my geodatabase to store some information for later use.  The user will be in ArcMap 9.3.1 with the geodatabase up and layers displayed.  I want to create the table at the same level as the dataset.  I can accomplish this with the following:

```
    gp = CreateObject("esriGeoprocessing.GPDispatch.1")
    gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Data Management Tools.tbx")
    gp.createtable_management("C:\Dan\Data\geodatabase.mdb", TableName, "", "")
```

However, the problem is I cannot figure out how to have the geodatabase be something other than hardcoded.  How do I get the current geodatabase name and use a variable populated with that name in the createtable_management line?

I've searched high and low for two days now with no luck.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well "C:\Dan\Data\geodatabase.mdb" is just a string so you can use a string variable set to some other value.

How you get the current gdb depends on what other objects you have.  For example if you have a IDataset its has a Workspace that has a PathName.

Also just to note, I believe that using "esriGeoprocessing.GPDispatch.1" is older syntax, you could use in .net a [Geoprocessor](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/ArcGISDesktop/dotnet/ViewCodePages/43d8cc77-5193-4ca8-9878-6027782e2bbbexecutetoolcopyfeatures.vb.htm) object.  Check out some of the sdk samples, prefixed with "GP" usually under C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit\SamplesNET\Desktop\, such as "GPExecutingTools"